# unable to changing a value in an object called file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change the value of name inside the file object . Any idea how i would go about it ?

```
  setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    console.log(file)
  const name = "john"
```

i want to change the name to "john" .

File {name: 'image1 (1).png', lastModified: 1671648766099, lastModifiedDate: Wed Dec 21 2022 21:52:46 GMT+0300...}

I have tried doing File['name'] = name but it did not work and it gives me App.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property name of # which has only a getter error

Comment: The `name` property on the [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File#instance_properties) object from the FilesList is read-only.